# If you went into a coma now and woke in twenty years time what would be your first post on MO?

Tags: big-list

This is just for fun. You can assume you retain full use of your faculties. I don't have anything to add to the question, although that may change depending on the responses. The twenty year time period is arbitrary.

Comment: Might it not be more suitable to ask, "the answer to which question would you seek among arXiv preprints?" 

Comment: This is, maybe, appropriate for a blog post.

Comment: I agree with Mariano.

Comment: I encourage votes to close.

Comment: Now that I have closed per the comments above, I will say that my first post would be an answer to this question (which I would lobby to have reopened under the circumstances) consisting of the sentence "Hello, world."

Comment: @Steve Huntsman: The "Hello, world" post would probably get more upvotes on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Given the reaction of the public, I'd rather ask not what your question would be, but how quickly will it be closed.

Comment: Guys -- how serious can one get? The question may look a bit silly but it can potentially generate some interesting answers. I for one would be interested to know what people think mathematics will look like in 20 years. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Pretty serious.  I have a technical question that has not yet been answered, and I resent people taking up the top spots with worthless and pointless questions like this.

Comment: Harry -- I also have several technical questions I'd very much like to see answered. But I don't seriously think that what prevents people from answering those is them spending hours trying to figure out a clever question to come up with on mathoverflow after 20 years is a coma.

Comment: @algori: the potential to generate interesting answers is not a valid reason to keep a question open.  As we've discussed on meta multiple times, almost any question has this property.

Answer (score 43):

Do people still ask a lot of inane questions on MO?

Answer (score 6):

Can't decide between "update me on the Millennium Problems" and "Is Wikipedia still there?"

Comment: Uh, you could just check the Clay Institute website and Wikipedia, respectively.

Comment: That kind of answer would certainly reassure me that noting much had changed. 

Comment: This answer-response might be the greatest thing on MO.